# Upgrading SSIS packages from SQL server 2005 to 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to move dozens of SSIS packages from SQL server 2005 to SQL 2008. We tried upgrading ssis packages to 2008 but they blewed away and it was not successful. Can somebody tell me the way to upgrade packages. What are some of the things that I have to change or keep in mind while upgrading the packages.

I am getting the following errors. And there are threee warnings like this.

> Warning 0x4020f42c: : The Maximum insert commit size property of the OLE DB destination "OLE DB Destination" is set to 0. This property setting can cause the running package to stop responding. For more information, see the F1 Help topic for OLE DB Destination Editor (Connection Manager Page).

Comment: Can you say what you mean by "blewed away"?

Comment: **Step 1** - Accept answers to your questions.  **Step 2** - Get more answers.  **Step 3** - ???? **Step 4** - Profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/upgarde_2005_packages_2008_i_p1.aspx

Comment: I tried the upgrade advisor. I  got errors for the Script Task. Do you know how can they be resolved

Comment: I am getting the following error. Please tell me how to resolve them . Thanks